# AngularJS Promises and $http interceptors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am trying to use this module to do http digest authentication.

https://github.com/PatrickHeneise/angular-digest-interceptor

Because it doesn't suit my needs 100%  I have made some minor changes too it.

```
  'use strict';

  angular.module('DigestAuthInterceptor', ['LocalStorageModule', 'angular-md5'])

  .config(function ($locationProvider, $provide) {
    $provide.factory('digestAuthInterceptor', function ($q, $injector, $location, localStorageService, md5) {
      return {
        responseError: function (rejection) {
          function genNonce(b) {
            var c = [],
              e = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
              a = e.length;
            for (var d = 0; d < b; ++d) {
              c.push(e[Math.random() * a | 0]);
            }
            return c.join('');
          }
          function unq(quotedString) {
            return quotedString.substr(1, quotedString.length - 2).replace(/(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+/g, ' ');
          }

          if (rejection.status === 401) {
            var
              $http = $injector.get('$http'),
              username = localStorageService.get('username'),
              password = localStorageService.get('password'),
              HA1 = localStorageService.get('authorization'),
              cnonce = genNonce(10),
              reg = /.+?\:\/\/.+?(\/.+?)(?:#|\?|$)/,
              nc = 1,
              nonce, realm, qop;

            if ((username && password) || HA1) {
              var
                ws = '(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+',
                token = '(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2E\\x30-\\x39\\x3F\\x41-\\x5A\\x5E-\\x7A\\x7C\\x7E]+)',
                quotedString = '"(?:[\\x00-\\x0B\\x0D-\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\\\x5D-\\x7F]|' + ws + '|\\\\[\\x00-\\x7F])*"',
                tokenizer = new RegExp(token + '(?:=(?:' + quotedString + '|' + token + '))?', 'g'),
                tokens = rejection.headers('WWW-Authenticate-X').match(tokenizer),
                // uri = reg.exec(rejection.config.url);

                uri = rejection.config.url;

              tokens.forEach(function (value) {
                if (value.match('nonce')) {
                  nonce = unq(value.split('=')[1]);
                }
                if (value.match('realm')) {
                  realm = unq(value.split('=')[1]);
                }
                if (value.match('qop')) {
                  qop   = unq(value.split('=')[1]);
                }
              });

              HA1 = HA1 ? HA1 : md5.createHash(username + ':' + realm + ':' + password);
              var
                HA2 = md5.createHash(rejection.config.method + ':' + uri),
                response = md5.createHash(HA1 + ':' + nonce + ':' + nc + ':' + cnonce + ':' + qop + ':' + HA2),
                header = 'Digest username="' + username + '", realm="' + realm +
                          '", nonce="' + nonce + '", uri="' + uri +
                          '", cnonce="' + cnonce + '", nc="' + nc +
                          '", qop="' + qop + '", response="' + response + '"';

              $http.defaults.headers.common.authorization = header;

              $http({
                method: rejection.config.method,
                url: rejection.config.url,
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType : 'application/json',
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': header
                }
              })
              .then(function(response){
                localStorageService.set('authorization', HA1);
                localStorageService.remove('password');
                return $q.defer(response);
              },function(error){
                return $q.reject(error);
              });
            } else {
              return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    });
  });
```

I have created a User factory with an authenticate function that is returned. When I call the User.authenticate("myusername","mypassword") and look at the Firebug console I see the 2 calls made to the server per the spec. The first rejected with a 401 and the second succeeding with a 200 response. So it authenticates and stores the ha1 hash in local storage. The problem I am having is that it seems because it calls a 401 first it calls the "error" promise instead of the "success" promise in the factory.  Every time I call a URI that is protected by http digest I am unable to trigger a "success" response and grab data even though I do "authenicate".  The "profile" function in the object shows what I have tried to do to get the promise to resolve, but I just don't see what I am doing wrong.

```
app.factory('User', ['$http','$q','localStorageService', function($http, $q, localStorageService)
{
  data = [];

  userFactory = {};

  userFactory.authenticate = function(username, password)
  {
    // Clear and set the credentials
    localStorageService.remove('username');
    localStorageService.remove('password');
    localStorageService.remove('authorization');
    localStorageService.add('username', username);
    localStorageService.add('password', password);

    return $http.post('/api/user/authenticate')
      .then(function(response)
        {
          console.log(response);

          if (typeof response.data.data === 'object')
          {
            return response.data;
          }
          else
          {
            return $q.reject(response.data);
          }
        }, function(error)
        {
          return $q.reject(error);
        });
  };

  userFactory.profile = function()
  {
    return $http.get('/api/user/profile')
      .then(function(response)
      {
        if(typeof response === 'object')
        {
          keys = Object.keys(response.data);
          for(key in keys)
          {
            data[key] = response.data[key];
          }
          console.log(data);
        }
        else
        {
          console.log('not object error');
        }

        return data;
      },
      function(error)
      {
        console.log('reject');
        console.log(error);
        // return reject
      });

      return data;
  };

  return userFactory
}]);
```

What I have noticed from the original module is that the author let's it manage where to send the user.  In the part where they respond to the auth request on failure they send them to a $location.path("/login").  I don't want it to manage the location, just if it authenticated or not and if so I want it to pass the requested data.  That way I can manage location in the main application.

Suggestions on resolving or if you know if a better module  (other than https://github.com/tafax/angular-digest-auth ) because that module stores usernames and passwords in plain text in the local/session storage.

Comment: Ever managed to solve it ? i¡m facing similar problems,

Comment: I don't remember, I can't even remember what I was trying to use this for...